# Shapely parallel_offset not found

Tags: python, attributeerror, shapely

I'm trying to use the Shapely `parallel_offset`, but it seems that it's not found.  I've included the imports found in the examples, but it just doesn't recognize `parallel_offset`.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from descartes import PolygonPatch

line=LineString([(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(2,0)])
offset = line.parallel_offset(1,'left',join_style=2)
```

And I get:

```
$ python parallel_offset.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parallel_offset.py", line 6, in <module>
    offset = line.parallel_offset(1,'left',join_style=2)
AttributeError: 'LineString' object has no attribute 'parallel_offset'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This feature has two requirements that both need to be met:

- Shapely >= 1.2.8
- GEOS >= 3.2.0

Answer (score 0):

I have copied 'few of your code lines' as below,and that worked too.

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString
line=LineString([(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(2,0)])
offset = line.parallel_offset(1,'left',join_style=2)
```

[I got the result as in the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mebvL.png).

The reason for you may be due to wrong installation, so install again with updated version.